# Set scroll focus on DataGrid edit mode

Tags: c#, datagrid, asp.net-2.0

I want to focus scroll position to editable row, but i need solution which could be used only in ascx page.

Comment: I tryied MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" in the top of the page and Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" but with second method maybe i don't know use it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Try This it may help you

```
 <pages maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" />
```

for more details [Link](https://weblogs.asp.net/hosamkamel/maintain-scroll-position-after-postbacks-in-asp-net-2-0)

Comment: Parser Error Message: The directive 'page' is unknown.

Source Error: 


Line 4:  <%@ Control Language="C#" %>
Line 5:  <%@ Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>

Comment: worked when I putted this in web.config and code in example in backend code